# Does model.save() save the model of the last epoch or the best epoch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

This single liner is used to save the keras deep learning neural network model.

```
model.save('my_model.h5')
```

Does `model.save()` save the model of the last epoch or the best epoch? Sometimes, the last epoch does not provide improvement to performance.

Comment: It should be the model state as it was at the end of training. As far as my understanding goes epochs are not seperate and are just a metric to determine number of times the model has seen the dataset?
https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It saves the model in its exact current state. If this statement is after the `Model#fit` method completion, then it represents the last epoch.

For best epoch (assuming best == smallest loss or greater accuracy), you can use the [ModelCheckpoint](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/) for this:

```py
epochs = 100
# other parameters...

model.fit(x, y,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=valid,
          verbose=2,
          callbacks=[
              TerminateOnNaN(),
              TensorBoard('./logs'),
              ModelCheckpoint('best.h5',
                              save_best_only=True),
              ...
          ])
# the model is holding the weights optimized for 100 epochs.
model.load_weights('best.h5')  # load weights that generated the min val loss.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. I think it makes sense to always use `ModelCheckpoint` to save the best model. Why would one save a model which is not the best? At least, I cannot imagine a better reason.

Comment: If training takes many hours and there's a change of power outage, then it makes sense to save the last one, even though it's not the best. That way, the process can be resumed if something goes wrong.

Comment: If the last epoch does not give the best weights, I think there is little learning loss even if we go back to an earlier epoch which gave the best weights.

Comment: Yet you cannot guarantee that this will result in the overall best result. If you would continue from the best state, you are likely to "train in the same way as before" (i.e. doing the same work twice), whereas starting from the latest (but maybe not best) state could result in *much better* results after a short while.

Comment: Isn't the "model.fit" returning the best model anyway (so don't have to save/load) ? It's not very clear in function explanation!

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the best weights are the ones retained after all training epochs (return of fit). `fit` runs for exactly `epochs*len(x) / batch-size` steps, and the best configuration might be obtained after a few of these steps, after which overfit occurs. It's common practice to monitor validation error periodically, and save intermediate weights that present better generalization capacity than the overfitted ones.